# rails-i18n translations seem to be not loaded

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, rails-i18n

**Stage**:

I have a Rails 3.2 application, I add to my `Gemfile`:

```
gem 'rails-i18n'
```

then I execute `bundle install`.

In a view I request a i18n message, for example:

```
<%= l Time.now, format: :short %>
```

and in `config/initializers/locate.rb`, I set default locate:

```
I18n.default_locale = :es
I18n.available_locales = :es
```

**Problem:**

```
I18n::MissingTranslationData in Events#index

translation missing: es.time.formats.short
```

What's wrong?
Is `rails-i18n` not loaded right?

**Test:**

Let's add `puts I18n.load_path` in `config/initializers/locate.rb` file:

I18n.default_locale = :es
   I18n.available_locales = :es

puts I18n.load_path

and then restart application, asi you can see there are listed all path loaded:

```
/home/foo/.rvm/gems/1.9.3@myapp/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/locale/en.yml
/home/foo/.rvm/gems/1.9.3@myapp/gems/activemodel-3.2.13/lib/active_model/locale/en.yml
/home/foo/.rvm/gems/1.9.3@myapp/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/locale/en.yml
/home/foo/.rvm/gems/1.9.3@myapp/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/action_view/locale/en.yml
/home/foo/.rvm/gems/1.9.3@myapp/gems/rails-i18n-0.7.3/rails/locale/es-MX.yml
/home/foo/.rvm/gems/1.9.3@myapp/gems/rails-i18n-0.7.3/rails/locale/es-PE.yml
/home/foo/.rvm/gems/1.9.3@myapp/gems/rails-i18n-0.7.3/rails/locale/es-VE.yml
/home/foo/.rvm/gems/1.9.3@myapp/gems/rails-i18n-0.7.3/rails/locale/zh-CN.yml
/home/foo/.rvm/gems/1.9.3@myapp/gems/rails-i18n-0.7.3/rails/locale/af.yml
/home/foo/.rvm/gems/1.9.3@myapp/gems/rails-i18n-0.7.3/rails/locale/bg.yml
/home/foo/.rvm/gems/1.9.3@myapp/gems/rails-i18n-0.7.3/rails/locale/ar.yml
/home/foo/.rvm/gems/1.9.3@myapp/gems/rails-i18n-0.7.3/rails/locale/ca.yml
/home/foo/.rvm/gems/1.9.3@myapp/gems/rails-i18n-0.7.3/rails/locale/bn.yml
/home/foo/.rvm/gems/1.9.3@myapp/gems/rails-i18n-0.7.3/rails/locale/az.yml
/home/foo/.rvm/gems/1.9.3@myapp/gems/rails-i18n-0.7.3/rails/locale/bs.yml
/home/foo/.rvm/gems/1.9.3@myapp/gems/rails-i18n-0.7.3/rails/locale/da.yml
/home/foo/.rvm/gems/1.9.3@myapp/gems/rails-i18n-0.7.3/rails/locale/de.yml
/home/foo/.rvm/gems/1.9.3@myapp/gems/rails-i18n-0.7.3/rails/locale/cs.yml
/home/foo/.rvm/gems/1.9.3@myapp/gems/rails-i18n-0.7.3/rails/locale/cy.yml
/home/foo/.rvm/gems/1.9.3@myapp/gems/rails-i18n-0.7.3/rails/locale/zh-TW.yml
/home/foo/.rvm/gems/1.9.3@myapp/gems/rails-i18n-0.7.3/rails/locale/fa.yml
/home/foo/.rvm/gems/1.9.3@myapp/gems/rails-i18n-0.7.3/rails/locale/el.yml
/home/foo/.rvm/gems/1.9.3@myapp/gems/rails-i18n-0.7.3/rails/locale/en.yml
/home/foo/.rvm/gems/1.9.3@myapp/gems/rails-i18n-0.7.3/rails/locale/eo.yml
/home/foo/.rvm/gems/1.9.3@myapp/gems/rails-i18n-0.7.3/rails/locale/es.yml
/home/foo/.rvm/gems/1.9.3@myapp/gems/rails-i18n-0.7.3/rails/locale/fi.yml
/home/foo/.rvm/gems/1.9.3@myapp/gems/rails-i18n-0.7.3/rails/locale/et.yml
/home/foo/.rvm/gems/1.9.3@myapp/gems/rails-i18n-0.7.3/rails/locale/eu.yml
/home/foo/.rvm/gems/1.9.3@myapp/gems/rails-i18n-0.7.3/rails/locale/fr.yml
/home/foo/.rvm/gems/1.9.3@myapp/gems/rails-i18n-0.7.3/rails/locale/gl.yml
/home/foo/.rvm/gems/1.9.3@myapp/gems/rails-i18n-0.7.3/rails/locale/he.yml
/home/foo/.rvm/gems/1.9.3@myapp/gems/rails-i18n-0.7.3/rails/locale/hi.yml
/home/foo/.rvm/gems/1.9.3@myapp/gems/rails-i18n-0.7.3/rails/locale/id.yml
/home/foo/.rvm/gems/1.9.3@myapp/gems/rails-i18n-0.7.3/rails/locale/hr.yml
/home/foo/.rvm/gems/1.9.3@myapp/gems/rails-i18n-0.7.3/rails/locale/hu.yml
/home/foo/.rvm/gems/1.9.3@myapp/gems/rails-i18n-0.7.3/rails/locale/ja.yml
/home/foo/.rvm/gems/1.9.3@myapp/gems/rails-i18n-0.7.3/rails/locale/is.yml
/home/foo/.rvm/gems/1.9.3@myapp/gems/rails-i18n-0.7.3/rails/locale/it.yml
/home/foo/.rvm/gems/1.9.3@myapp/gems/rails-i18n-0.7.3/rails/locale/kn.yml
/home/foo/.rvm/gems/1.9.3@myapp/gems/rails-i18n-0.7.3/rails/locale/ko.yml
/home/foo/.rvm/gems/1.9.3@myapp/gems/rails-i18n-0.7.3/rails/locale/lo.yml
/home/foo/.rvm/gems/1.9.3@myapp/gems/rails-i18n-0.7.3/rails/locale/lt.yml
/home/foo/.rvm/gems/1.9.3@myapp/gems/rails-i18n-0.7.3/rails/locale/mk.yml
/home/foo/.rvm/gems/1.9.3@myapp/gems/rails-i18n-0.7.3/rails/locale/lv.yml
/home/foo/.rvm/gems/1.9.3@myapp/gems/rails-i18n-0.7.3/rails/locale/nb.yml
/home/foo/.rvm/gems/1.9.3@myapp/gems/rails-i18n-0.7.3/rails/locale/hi-IN.yml
/home/foo/.rvm/gems/1.9.3@myapp/gems/rails-i18n-0.7.3/rails/locale/mn.yml
/home/foo/.rvm/gems/1.9.3@myapp/gems/rails-i18n-0.7.3/rails/locale/ne.yml
/home/foo/.rvm/gems/1.9.3@myapp/gems/rails-i18n-0.7.3/rails/locale/nl.yml
/home/foo/.rvm/gems/1.9.3@myapp/gems/rails-i18n-0.7.3/rails/locale/nn.yml
/home/foo/.rvm/gems/1.9.3@myapp/gems/rails-i18n-0.7.3/rails/locale/pl.yml
/home/foo/.rvm/gems/1.9.3@myapp/gems/rails-i18n-0.7.3/rails/locale/pt.yml
/home/foo/.rvm/gems/1.9.3@myapp/gems/rails-i18n-0.7.3/rails/locale/rm.yml
/home/foo/.rvm/gems/1.9.3@myapp/gems/rails-i18n-0.7.3/rails/locale/ro.yml
/home/foo/.rvm/gems/1.9.3@myapp/gems/rails-i18n-0.7.3/rails/locale/ru.yml
/home/foo/.rvm/gems/1.9.3@myapp/gems/rails-i18n-0.7.3/rails/locale/sk.yml
/home/foo/.rvm/gems/1.9.3@myapp/gems/rails-i18n-0.7.3/rails/locale/sl.yml
/home/foo/.rvm/gems/1.9.3@myapp/gems/rails-i18n-0.7.3/rails/locale/sr.yml
/home/foo/.rvm/gems/1.9.3@myapp/gems/rails-i18n-0.7.3/rails/locale/th.yml
/home/foo/.rvm/gems/1.9.3@myapp/gems/rails-i18n-0.7.3/rails/locale/sv.yml
/home/foo/.rvm/gems/1.9.3@myapp/gems/rails-i18n-0.7.3/rails/locale/tl.yml
/home/foo/.rvm/gems/1.9.3@myapp/gems/rails-i18n-0.7.3/rails/locale/sw.yml
/home/foo/.rvm/gems/1.9.3@myapp/gems/rails-i18n-0.7.3/rails/locale/tr.yml
/home/foo/.rvm/gems/1.9.3@myapp/gems/rails-i18n-0.7.3/rails/locale/uk.yml
/home/foo/.rvm/gems/1.9.3@myapp/gems/rails-i18n-0.7.3/rails/locale/vi.yml
/home/foo/.rvm/gems/1.9.3@myapp/gems/rails-i18n-0.7.3/rails/locale/uz.yml
/home/foo/.rvm/gems/1.9.3@myapp/gems/rails-i18n-0.7.3/rails/locale/wo.yml
/home/foo/.rvm/gems/1.9.3@myapp/gems/rails-i18n-0.7.3/rails/locale/it-CH.yml
/home/foo/.rvm/gems/1.9.3@myapp/gems/rails-i18n-0.7.3/rails/locale/en-AU.yml
/home/foo/.rvm/gems/1.9.3@myapp/gems/rails-i18n-0.7.3/rails/locale/en-CA.yml
/home/foo/.rvm/gems/1.9.3@myapp/gems/rails-i18n-0.7.3/rails/locale/pt-BR.yml
/home/foo/.rvm/gems/1.9.3@myapp/gems/rails-i18n-0.7.3/rails/locale/en-GB.yml
/home/foo/.rvm/gems/1.9.3@myapp/gems/rails-i18n-0.7.3/rails/locale/de-AT.yml
/home/foo/.rvm/gems/1.9.3@myapp/gems/rails-i18n-0.7.3/rails/locale/fr-CA.yml
/home/foo/.rvm/gems/1.9.3@myapp/gems/rails-i18n-0.7.3/rails/locale/fr-CH.yml
/home/foo/.rvm/gems/1.9.3@myapp/gems/rails-i18n-0.7.3/rails/locale/de-CH.yml
/home/foo/.rvm/gems/1.9.3@myapp/gems/rails-i18n-0.7.3/rails/locale/es-AR.yml
/home/foo/.rvm/gems/1.9.3@myapp/gems/rails-i18n-0.7.3/rails/locale/en-IN.yml
/home/foo/.rvm/gems/1.9.3@myapp/gems/rails-i18n-0.7.3/rails/locale/es-CL.yml
/home/foo/.rvm/gems/1.9.3@myapp/gems/rails-i18n-0.7.3/rails/locale/es-CO.yml
/home/foo/.rvm/gems/1.9.3@myapp/gems/rails-i18n-0.7.3/rails/locale/es-419.yml
/home/foo/.rvm/gems/1.9.3@myapp/gems/rails-i18n-0.7.3/rails/pluralization/ak.rb
/home/foo/.rvm/gems/1.9.3@myapp/gems/rails-i18n-0.7.3/rails/pluralization/am.rb
/home/foo/.rvm/gems/1.9.3@myapp/gems/rails-i18n-0.7.3/rails/pluralization/be.rb
/home/foo/.rvm/gems/1.9.3@myapp/gems/rails-i18n-0.7.3/rails/pluralization/bg.rb
/home/foo/.rvm/gems/1.9.3@myapp/gems/rails-i18n-0.7.3/rails/pluralization/ar.rb
/home/foo/.rvm/gems/1.9.3@myapp/gems/rails-i18n-0.7.3/rails/pluralization/bh.rb
/home/foo/.rvm/gems/1.9.3@myapp/gems/rails-i18n-0.7.3/rails/pluralization/ca.rb
/home/foo/.rvm/gems/1.9.3@myapp/gems/rails-i18n-0.7.3/rails/pluralization/bm.rb
/home/foo/.rvm/gems/1.9.3@myapp/gems/rails-i18n-0.7.3/rails/pluralization/bn.rb
/home/foo/.rvm/gems/1.9.3@myapp/gems/rails-i18n-0.7.3/rails/pluralization/bo.rb
/home/foo/.rvm/gems/1.9.3@myapp/gems/rails-i18n-0.7.3/rails/pluralization/az.rb
/home/foo/.rvm/gems/1.9.3@myapp/gems/rails-i18n-0.7.3/rails/pluralization/br.rb
/home/foo/.rvm/gems/1.9.3@myapp/gems/rails-i18n-0.7.3/rails/pluralization/bs.rb
/home/foo/.rvm/gems/1.9.3@myapp/gems/rails-i18n-0.7.3/rails/pluralization/da.rb
/home/foo/.rvm/gems/1.9.3@myapp/gems/rails-i18n-0.7.3/rails/pluralization/by.rb
/home/foo/.rvm/gems/1.9.3@myapp/gems/rails-i18n-0.7.3/rails/pluralization/de.rb
/home/foo/.rvm/gems/1.9.3@myapp/gems/rails-i18n-0.7.3/rails/pluralization/cs.rb
/home/foo/.rvm/gems/1.9.3@myapp/gems/rails-i18n-0.7.3/rails/pluralization/cy.rb
/home/foo/.rvm/gems/1.9.3@myapp/gems/rails-i18n-0.7.3/rails/pluralization/el.rb
/home/foo/.rvm/gems/1.9.3@myapp/gems/rails-i18n-0.7.3/rails/pluralization/fa.rb
/home/foo/.rvm/gems/1.9.3@myapp/gems/rails-i18n-0.7.3/rails/pluralization/en.rb
/home/foo/.rvm/gems/1.9.3@myapp/gems/rails-i18n-0.7.3/rails/pluralization/eo.rb
/home/foo/.rvm/gems/1.9.3@myapp/gems/rails-i18n-0.7.3/rails/pluralization/dz.rb
/home/foo/.rvm/gems/1.9.3@myapp/gems/rails-i18n-0.7.3/rails/pluralization/ff.rb
/home/foo/.rvm/gems/1.9.3@myapp/gems/rails-i18n-0.7.3/rails/pluralization/es.rb
/home/foo/.rvm/gems/1.9.3@myapp/gems/rails-i18n-0.7.3/rails/pluralization/fi.rb
/home/foo/.rvm/gems/1.9.3@myapp/gems/rails-i18n-0.7.3/rails/pluralization/et.rb
/home/foo/.rvm/gems/1.9.3@myapp/gems/rails-i18n-0.7.3/rails/pluralization/eu.rb
/home/foo/.rvm/gems/1.9.3@myapp/gems/rails-i18n-0.7.3/rails/pluralization/ga.rb
/home/foo/.rvm/gems/1.9.3@myapp/gems/rails-i18n-0.7.3/rails/pluralization/gd.rb
/home/foo/.rvm/gems/1.9.3@myapp/gems/rails-i18n-0.7.3/rails/pluralization/fr.rb
/home/foo/.rvm/gems/1.9.3@myapp/gems/rails-i18n-0.7.3/rails/pluralization/gl.rb
/home/foo/.rvm/gems/1.9.3@myapp/gems/rails-i18n-0.7.3/rails/pluralization/he.rb
/home/foo/.rvm/gems/1.9.3@myapp/gems/rails-i18n-0.7.3/rails/pluralization/hi.rb
/home/foo/.rvm/gems/1.9.3@myapp/gems/rails-i18n-0.7.3/rails/pluralization/gv.rb
/home/foo/.rvm/gems/1.9.3@myapp/gems/rails-i18n-0.7.3/rails/pluralization/id.rb
/home/foo/.rvm/gems/1.9.3@myapp/gems/rails-i18n-0.7.3/rails/pluralization/ig.rb
/home/foo/.rvm/gems/1.9.3@myapp/gems/rails-i18n-0.7.3/rails/pluralization/hr.rb
/home/foo/.rvm/gems/1.9.3@myapp/gems/rails-i18n-0.7.3/rails/pluralization/ii.rb
/home/foo/.rvm/gems/1.9.3@myapp/gems/rails-i18n-0.7.3/rails/pluralization/hu.rb
/home/foo/.rvm/gems/1.9.3@myapp/gems/rails-i18n-0.7.3/rails/pluralization/ja.rb
/home/foo/.rvm/gems/1.9.3@myapp/gems/rails-i18n-0.7.3/rails/pluralization/is.rb
/home/foo/.rvm/gems/1.9.3@myapp/gems/rails-i18n-0.7.3/rails/pluralization/it.rb
/home/foo/.rvm/gems/1.9.3@myapp/gems/rails-i18n-0.7.3/rails/pluralization/iu.rb
/home/foo/.rvm/gems/1.9.3@myapp/gems/rails-i18n-0.7.3/rails/pluralization/ka.rb
/home/foo/.rvm/gems/1.9.3@myapp/gems/rails-i18n-0.7.3/rails/pluralization/jv.rb
/home/foo/.rvm/gems/1.9.3@myapp/gems/rails-i18n-0.7.3/rails/pluralization/km.rb
/home/foo/.rvm/gems/1.9.3@myapp/gems/rails-i18n-0.7.3/rails/pluralization/kn.rb
/home/foo/.rvm/gems/1.9.3@myapp/gems/rails-i18n-0.7.3/rails/pluralization/ko.rb
/home/foo/.rvm/gems/1.9.3@myapp/gems/rails-i18n-0.7.3/rails/pluralization/kw.rb
/home/foo/.rvm/gems/1.9.3@myapp/gems/rails-i18n-0.7.3/rails/pluralization/ln.rb
/home/foo/.rvm/gems/1.9.3@myapp/gems/rails-i18n-0.7.3/rails/pluralization/lo.rb
/home/foo/.rvm/gems/1.9.3@myapp/gems/rails-i18n-0.7.3/rails/pluralization/mg.rb
/home/foo/.rvm/gems/1.9.3@myapp/gems/rails-i18n-0.7.3/rails/pluralization/lt.rb
/home/foo/.rvm/gems/1.9.3@myapp/gems/rails-i18n-0.7.3/rails/pluralization/mk.rb
/home/foo/.rvm/gems/1.9.3@myapp/gems/rails-i18n-0.7.3/rails/pluralization/lv.rb
/home/foo/.rvm/gems/1.9.3@myapp/gems/rails-i18n-0.7.3/rails/pluralization/nb.rb
/home/foo/.rvm/gems/1.9.3@myapp/gems/rails-i18n-0.7.3/rails/pluralization/mn.rb
/home/foo/.rvm/gems/1.9.3@myapp/gems/rails-i18n-0.7.3/rails/pluralization/mo.rb
/home/foo/.rvm/gems/1.9.3@myapp/gems/rails-i18n-0.7.3/rails/pluralization/ne.rb
/home/foo/.rvm/gems/1.9.3@myapp/gems/rails-i18n-0.7.3/rails/pluralization/ms.rb
/home/foo/.rvm/gems/1.9.3@myapp/gems/rails-i18n-0.7.3/rails/pluralization/mt.rb
/home/foo/.rvm/gems/1.9.3@myapp/gems/rails-i18n-0.7.3/rails/pluralization/nl.rb
/home/foo/.rvm/gems/1.9.3@myapp/gems/rails-i18n-0.7.3/rails/pluralization/nn.rb
/home/foo/.rvm/gems/1.9.3@myapp/gems/rails-i18n-0.7.3/rails/pluralization/my.rb
/home/foo/.rvm/gems/1.9.3@myapp/gems/rails-i18n-0.7.3/rails/pluralization/pl.rb
/home/foo/.rvm/gems/1.9.3@myapp/gems/rails-i18n-0.7.3/rails/pluralization/ro.rb
/home/foo/.rvm/gems/1.9.3@myapp/gems/rails-i18n-0.7.3/rails/pluralization/se.rb
/home/foo/.rvm/gems/1.9.3@myapp/gems/rails-i18n-0.7.3/rails/pluralization/sg.rb
/home/foo/.rvm/gems/1.9.3@myapp/gems/rails-i18n-0.7.3/rails/pluralization/sh.rb
/home/foo/.rvm/gems/1.9.3@myapp/gems/rails-i18n-0.7.3/rails/pluralization/ru.rb
/home/foo/.rvm/gems/1.9.3@myapp/gems/rails-i18n-0.7.3/rails/pluralization/sk.rb
/home/foo/.rvm/gems/1.9.3@myapp/gems/rails-i18n-0.7.3/rails/pluralization/sl.rb
/home/foo/.rvm/gems/1.9.3@myapp/gems/rails-i18n-0.7.3/rails/pluralization/sr.rb
/home/foo/.rvm/gems/1.9.3@myapp/gems/rails-i18n-0.7.3/rails/pluralization/th.rb
/home/foo/.rvm/gems/1.9.3@myapp/gems/rails-i18n-0.7.3/rails/pluralization/ti.rb
/home/foo/.rvm/gems/1.9.3@myapp/gems/rails-i18n-0.7.3/rails/pluralization/sv.rb
/home/foo/.rvm/gems/1.9.3@myapp/gems/rails-i18n-0.7.3/rails/pluralization/tl.rb
/home/foo/.rvm/gems/1.9.3@myapp/gems/rails-i18n-0.7.3/rails/pluralization/sw.rb
/home/foo/.rvm/gems/1.9.3@myapp/gems/rails-i18n-0.7.3/rails/pluralization/to.rb
/home/foo/.rvm/gems/1.9.3@myapp/gems/rails-i18n-0.7.3/rails/pluralization/tr.rb
/home/foo/.rvm/gems/1.9.3@myapp/gems/rails-i18n-0.7.3/rails/pluralization/uk.rb
/home/foo/.rvm/gems/1.9.3@myapp/gems/rails-i18n-0.7.3/rails/pluralization/vi.rb
/home/foo/.rvm/gems/1.9.3@myapp/gems/rails-i18n-0.7.3/rails/pluralization/wa.rb
/home/foo/.rvm/gems/1.9.3@myapp/gems/rails-i18n-0.7.3/rails/pluralization/wo.rb
/home/foo/.rvm/gems/1.9.3@myapp/gems/rails-i18n-0.7.3/rails/pluralization/yo.rb
/home/foo/.rvm/gems/1.9.3@myapp/gems/rails-i18n-0.7.3/rails/pluralization/zh.rb
/home/foo/.rvm/gems/1.9.3@myapp/gems/rails-i18n-0.7.3/rails/pluralization/root.rb
/home/foo/.rvm/gems/1.9.3@myapp/gems/rails-i18n-0.7.3/rails/pluralization/es-AR.rb
/home/foo/.rvm/gems/1.9.3@myapp/gems/rails-i18n-0.7.3/rails/pluralization/es-CL.rb
/home/foo/.rvm/gems/1.9.3@myapp/gems/rails-i18n-0.7.3/rails/pluralization/es-CO.rb
/home/foo/.rvm/gems/1.9.3@myapp/gems/rails-i18n-0.7.3/rails/pluralization/es-MX.rb
/home/foo/.rvm/gems/1.9.3@myapp/gems/rails-i18n-0.7.3/rails/pluralization/es-PE.rb
/home/foo/.rvm/gems/1.9.3@myapp/gems/rails-i18n-0.7.3/rails/pluralization/es-VE.rb
/home/foo/.rvm/gems/1.9.3@myapp/gems/rails-i18n-0.7.3/rails/pluralization/zh-CN.rb
/home/foo/.rvm/gems/1.9.3@myapp/gems/rails-i18n-0.7.3/rails/pluralization/zh-TW.rb
/home/foo/.rvm/gems/1.9.3@myapp/gems/rails-i18n-0.7.3/rails/pluralization/fil.rb
/home/foo/.rvm/gems/1.9.3@myapp/gems/rails-i18n-0.7.3/rails/pluralization/guw.rb
/home/foo/.rvm/gems/1.9.3@myapp/gems/rails-i18n-0.7.3/rails/pluralization/hsb.rb
/home/foo/.rvm/gems/1.9.3@myapp/gems/rails-i18n-0.7.3/rails/pluralization/kab.rb
/home/foo/.rvm/gems/1.9.3@myapp/gems/rails-i18n-0.7.3/rails/pluralization/kde.rb
/home/foo/.rvm/gems/1.9.3@myapp/gems/rails-i18n-0.7.3/rails/pluralization/kea.rb
/home/foo/.rvm/gems/1.9.3@myapp/gems/rails-i18n-0.7.3/rails/pluralization/lag.rb
/home/foo/.rvm/gems/1.9.3@myapp/gems/rails-i18n-0.7.3/rails/pluralization/ksh.rb
/home/foo/.rvm/gems/1.9.3@myapp/gems/rails-i18n-0.7.3/rails/pluralization/naq.rb
/home/foo/.rvm/gems/1.9.3@myapp/gems/rails-i18n-0.7.3/rails/pluralization/nso.rb
/home/foo/.rvm/gems/1.9.3@myapp/gems/rails-i18n-0.7.3/rails/pluralization/en-AU.rb
/home/foo/.rvm/gems/1.9.3@myapp/gems/rails-i18n-0.7.3/rails/pluralization/en-CA.rb
/home/foo/.rvm/gems/1.9.3@myapp/gems/rails-i18n-0.7.3/rails/pluralization/en-GB.rb
/home/foo/.rvm/gems/1.9.3@myapp/gems/rails-i18n-0.7.3/rails/pluralization/en-IN.rb
/home/foo/.rvm/gems/1.9.3@myapp/gems/rails-i18n-0.7.3/rails/pluralization/es-419.rb
/home/foo/.rvm/gems/1.9.3@myapp/gems/rails-i18n-0.7.3/rails/pluralization/sah.rb
/home/foo/.rvm/gems/1.9.3@myapp/gems/rails-i18n-0.7.3/rails/pluralization/ses.rb
/home/foo/.rvm/gems/1.9.3@myapp/gems/rails-i18n-0.7.3/rails/pluralization/shi.rb
/home/foo/.rvm/gems/1.9.3@myapp/gems/rails-i18n-0.7.3/rails/pluralization/sma.rb
/home/foo/.rvm/gems/1.9.3@myapp/gems/rails-i18n-0.7.3/rails/pluralization/smi.rb
/home/foo/.rvm/gems/1.9.3@myapp/gems/rails-i18n-0.7.3/rails/pluralization/smj.rb
/home/foo/.rvm/gems/1.9.3@myapp/gems/rails-i18n-0.7.3/rails/pluralization/smn.rb
/home/foo/.rvm/gems/1.9.3@myapp/gems/rails-i18n-0.7.3/rails/pluralization/sms.rb
/home/foo/.rvm/gems/1.9.3@myapp/gems/rails-i18n-0.7.3/rails/pluralization/hi-IN.rb
/home/foo/.rvm/gems/1.9.3@myapp/gems/rails-i18n-0.7.3/rails/pluralization/tzm.rb
/home/foo/.rvm/gems/1.9.3@myapp/gems/rails-i18n-0.7.3/rails/pluralization/de-AT.rb
/home/foo/.rvm/gems/1.9.3@myapp/gems/rails-i18n-0.7.3/rails/pluralization/de-CH.rb
/home/foo/.rvm/gems/1.9.3@myapp/gems/rails-i18n-0.7.3/rails/pluralization/fr-CA.rb
/home/foo/.rvm/gems/1.9.3@myapp/gems/rails-i18n-0.7.3/rails/pluralization/fr-CH.rb
/home/foo/.rvm/gems/1.9.3@myapp/gems/rails-i18n-0.7.3/rails/pluralization/it-CH.rb
/home/foo/.rvm/gems/1.9.3@myapp/gems/rails-i18n-0.7.3/rails/transliteration/ru.rb
/home/foo/.rvm/gems/1.9.3@myapp/gems/rails-i18n-0.7.3/rails/transliteration/uk.rb
/home/foo/.rvm/gems/1.9.3@myapp/gems/rails-i18n-0.7.3/rails/transliteration/bg.yml
/home/foo/.rvm/gems/1.9.3@myapp/gems/rails-i18n-0.7.3/rails/transliteration/hu.yml
/home/foo/.rvm/gems/1.9.3@myapp/gems/rails-i18n-0.7.3/rails/transliteration/pl.yml
/home/foo/.rvm/gems/1.9.3@myapp/gems/rails-i18n-0.7.3/rails/transliteration/vi.yml
```

In this list there is `es` messages.

Again, what's wrong?

Comment: Did you end up solving this issue? If yes, how did you resolve it?

Answer (score 6):

It is available only in Rails' defaults for English - `en.yml`.

You have to add this lines to your `es.yml`:

```
es:
  time:
    formats:
      default: "%Y/%m/%d"
      short: "%b %d"
      long: "%B %d, %Y"
```

See full story [here (Wayback Machine link)](https://web.archive.org/web/20130502171346/http://www.apptastic.com.au/blog/13-months-in-the-rails-year) and in [the Rails docs](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#adding-date-time-formats).

Comment: If I must add my own messages so what is the reason to use `rails-i18n` gem. I have added **test** section to give more details in my description above.

Comment: Add this line to locate.rb: I18n.load_path += Dir[Rails.root.join('lib', 'locale', '*.{rb,yml}')]

Comment: I did not work, it throws `translation missing: es.time.formats.long` :(

Comment: Rails only has :en locale by default but you can extend this by using the rails-i18n gem. https://github.com/svenfuchs/rails-i18n/blob/master/rails/locale/es.yml